# Automatically update and scroll to the end a page showing raw text

Tags: html, logging, scroll, updates

I have got a desktop application which logs into a file, opening a file called `application.log` each time it wants to log something, appending text and then closing it again.

I would like to create a html page showing the content of the file and automatically showing the changes.

How can I achieve this? I think that refreshing the page is not a good idea because this is not instantaneous. Maybe I need something always going in the background, constantly monitoring the file.

Or maybe when my program changes the file it should somehow notify the webpage that the file had changed, making it update the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do dynamic things in HTML. HTML is just a mark up language.

I haven’t done that before, but I would try to achieve it with Java Script and the reload() function every time you logged sth.

Comment: of course I mean an HTML page containing .js funcions

Comment: Have you any further progress? Have you tried something ? What kind of application is it from which you want to write in your log file?

Comment: I have got enormous progress, I will post my answer

Answer (score 0):

I cloned this https://github.com/Chainfrog-dev/async_flask_2, it is a Python module which communicates with a web page using sockets.

I made the obvious modifications to the code and I ended up with a terminal-style logger which automatically updates its content without the need to refresh the page.